# Json Data Filteration according to category

Tags: android, json

I want to know how to filter data. I got data with category name but cannot filter category wise.Here is my data:

```
  {
    "TITLE": "tea",
    "PRICE": "17",
    "QTY": "1",
    "CAT_ID": "33",
    "CAT_NAME": "POPULAR PRODUCTS",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
  {
    "TITLE": "Coffee",
    "PRICE": "102",
    "QTY": "1 ",
    "CAT_ID": "8",
    "CAT_NAME": "MORNING SPECIAL",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
  {
    "TITLE": "Jeera chachh",
    "PRICE": "42",
    "QTY": "1",
    "CAT_ID": "33",
    "CAT_NAME": "POPULAR PRODUCTS",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
  {
    "TITLE": "Roti Ghee Wali",
    "PRICE": "21",
    "QTY": "1",
    "CAT_ID": "33",
    "CAT_NAME": "POPULAR PRODUCTS",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
  {
    "TITLE": "Paneer paratha",
    "PRICE": "102",
    "QTY": "1 ",
    "CAT_ID": "8",
    "CAT_NAME": "MORNING SPECIAL",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
  {
    "TITLE": "Mix paratha",
    "PRICE": "102",
    "QTY": "1",
    "CAT_ID": "8",
    "CAT_NAME": "MORNING SPECIAL",
    "TYPE": "veg"
  },
```

I already parse the data but not able to set in fragment according to category.Can anyone solve my issue.

Comment: what have you tried so far, try posting your code here

Comment: from above json, I need Title and Price from every index having same and differentb CAT_NAME.   Means   I hv to group every TITLE n PRICE according to their CAT_NAME. Because CAT_NAME are same in most of the indexes.

Comment: Is above is your complete json reponse or part of response? because above json value is not a complete correct json

Comment: I hv added the rest of json. Its part of main\ json

Comment: Still not a correct json either all above code covered by {...code..},[..code..] .. { -jsonobject .. [..jsonArray .. but if above response is final you can seperate string by (,) then store each string as jsonobject then you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Store the data in database.

**Step 2:** Search 
`select * from table where CAT_NAME = 'your_filter_category'`.
or better `....CAT_NAME like %your_filter_category%`.

In Case of no database;

Store the Data in list.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> map = new HashMap<>();

ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

Loop on List{
    Item item = fromLoop index;

    if(map.contains(item.getCat())){
        itemList = map.get(item.getCat());
        itemList.put(item);
        map.put(item.getCat(),itemList);

    }else{
        itemList.clear();
        itemList.put(item);
        map.put(item.getCat(),itemList);
    }
}

//after loop you will get HashMap with keys as categories and Values as the list of selected key category.
```

**Step 3:** Publish the results.

**Note:** No one will do your homework here. the only thing we can do for you, we can assist you how to do.

Comment: then store it in temp data structure, lets say.. `Hashmap<String : catname, ArrayList<items>>`.

Comment: or u can use.. Simple ArrayList<items> and loop on its to find the desired category.

Answer (score 0):

enter your code to: [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and you will see that something is invalid in your JSON, it has multiple root elements. Maybe you should store whole code in JSONArray like this: `

```
{
"features":
 [{ 
  "TITLE": "tea", 
  "PRICE": "17", 
  "QTY": "1", 
  "CAT_ID":"33", 
  "CAT_NAME": "POPULAR PRODUCTS", 
  "TYPE": "veg" },
  { 
  "TITLE":"Coffee", 
  "PRICE": "102", 
  "QTY": "1 ", 
  "CAT_ID": "8",
  "CAT_NAME":"MORNING SPECIAL", 
  "TYPE": "veg" 
}]
}
```

Comment: I have checked that. Its valid json.